# jQuery GT with self element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('li.pagination:gt(0):lt(4)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="0"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="1"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="2"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="3"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="4"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="5"><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="6"><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="7"><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="8"><a href="#">9</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="9"><a href="#">10</a></li>
```

I want to hide LI from 1-5. How can I achieve this? GT and LT value coming dynamically so instead of suggesting another solution please tell me How can I achieve a result in this solution.

Comment: `gt(-1)` works in jQuery >= 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `:gt(0):` pert, you only need `$('li.pagination:lt(4)').hide();`

If you want to hide 5 , use `$('li.pagination:lt(5)').hide();` because your numbers starts from 1 and your `data-page` starts at 0.

```js
$('li.pagination:lt(5)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="0"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="1"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="2"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="3"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="4"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="5"><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="6"><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="7"><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="8"><a href="#">9</a></li>
<li class="pagination" data-page="9"><a href="#">10</a></li>
```

Comment: To quote OP "GT and LT value coming dynamically" so your solution should include `gt()`

Comment: The not right solution I already told GT and LT value coming dynamically.

Comment: you mean 0 and 4 will always be the GT and LT values?

Comment: @ashik no it is a dynamic value.

Comment: as  Federico klez Culloca mentioned in the comment, try `gt(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this iteration. Prevents the duplication of writing `$('li.pagination:lt(???)').hide();` 5 times and,if wanting to add more elements to hide, can just expand the array instead of duplicating another line.

```
let numbersToHide = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$("li").each(function (elem) {
    if (numbersToHide.indexOf(elem.innerHTML) > -1) {
        elem.hide();
    }
}
```